# What is an example of a “clean” redivider?

Tags: etymology, humor

Most [redividers](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/redivider) are vulgar or rude in some way, for example

- therapist -> the rapist
- pen island -> penis land
- an album cover -> anal bum cover

I am looking for a "clean" example of this, no references to genitals, indecencies, etc.

The closest I've found is

- In every ode linger many -> I never yodel in Germany

I'm looking for an example to use in a programming course to emphasize the importance of spacing. The course is taught to middle-schoolers at an institution where I would not be able to make references like this. So I'm looking for something that kids would understand and is clean enough to not offend any parents.

I'm not the biggest fan of "In every ode linger many", since it's a nonsense phrase. If one interpretation is obviously superior to the other, I think it will make it harder to see that spacing really matters.

Comment: Scanning the words used in your question, I see (1) **some** → **so me**, (2) **example** → **ex ample**, and (3) **offend** → **off end** (I am discounting the words **something** and **understand**; even though they technically are, they don't form distinct enough separate words.) I only looked at individual words. It's possible phrases used in the question could also result in something else.

Comment: But, unfortunately, I don't see how this question can lead to more than just a list, which is actually off topic.

Comment: This might get some interesting answers at [puzzling.se].

Comment: Puzzling.SE is more appropriate for anagrams, palindromes, inclusions and the like.

Comment: The link you give specifies sentences rather than non-sentential strings such as your 
 examples. _captor mediator emulate browsable intent acerate woolens warden ..._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about *hotdog* --> *hot dog*? Clean; understandable, even for middle schoolers; non-offensive; and short. Note that *redivider* is a palindrome.

Answer (score 6):

- just + ice
- quest + ion
- arc +  her
- pass + age
- friend + ship
- imp + art

I have just spent an hour and a half finding three pages of them for my Year 5 11+ group!!

Answer (score 6):

This one goes back to the 19th century:

Am I able to get her ~ Amiable together

Some time in the 1990s I read of when someone converted some code from one language to another, using an app. The first language allowed upper and lower case letters and _ in names, Like_This, but the second language didn't, so the app removed the underscores and made each name a solid run of lower-case letters. One of the names was live_RSA_usage.

Answer (score 4):

- star training -> start raining
- first ripe -> fir stripe

Answer (score 3):

These are quite clean:

- car|pet (this is even used in that [JavaScript quote](https://devrant.com/rants/41451/java-is-to-javascript-what-car-is-to-carpet-chris-heilmann))
- thin|king
- man|go

And there's these that are kind of clean but not entirely (negative in at least in some contexts, but might still be useful to others):

- sham|poo
- gas|ping
- in|sect
- am|using
- car|rot